# Flash AS3 Can I get the original file binary content of the main swf on startup?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Can I get the file's binary content of the stage-owner, main swf on startup ?

LoaderInfo.bytes is not equal to the file.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this dynamically in Flash Player by itself, if you're using AIR you have access to the FileStream class and can read in any file byte by byte, alternatively I know you can embed a file then read it's contents as a bytearray but this requires knowing the file name in advance of compilation.

Answer (score 0):

*LoaderInfo.bytes is not equal to the file* because it unpacked.